# 'Unrecognized task verify' while verifying smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat, etherscan

verify task not found in hardhat pre-defined tasks in hardhat package.

```
Error HH303: Unrecognized task verify

HardhatError: HH303: Unrecognized task verify
    at main (/home/oem/Documents/final-rain-sdk/rain-sdk/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/cli/cli.ts:226:15)
```

[hardhat.config.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZWYa.png)
$ the command i ran: npx hardhat verify --network eth 0x5f140EA4e08D1aF9F41fA4cf935FC7a98EF4FfF8 --show-stack-traces

I tried to verify using task with

```
     await hre.run("verify:verify", {
       address: "0x5f140EA4e08D1aF9F41fA4cf935FC7a98EF4FfF8",
       contract: "contracts/stake/StakeFactory.sol:StakeFactory",
       constructorArguments: [],
     });
```

I tried using the cli as well.
nothing works.
while all the env variables are attaching correctly in the config file

Comment: Is your network  "eth" as shown in the file?

Comment: yes, i ran this command.
$ `npx hardhat verify --network eth 0x5f140EA4e08D1aF9F41fA4cf935FC7a98EF4FfF8`

Comment: RPC endpoint, and API_KEY are also pointing to the 'eth' network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, resolved it at my end
the thing is, I imported `@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan` in hardhat.config and the task in created in my `deploy.ts` file.
So you need to import `@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan` plugin into your `deploy.ts` file where the verify task is created.